# Stackoverflowexception on returning list<object>

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I am trying to doing an fetch call to retrieve a list of objects and just print its content for now. when the call is made a 502.3 error and stackoverflowexception error happens on the return call. See code below

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
    public async Task<List<Portfolio>> GetAllPortfolios()
    {
        var portfolios = await _portfolioService.GetAllPortfolios().ConfigureAwait(false);
        return portfolios;
    }
```

I tried to return an empty list and that ran fine with 200 status.

Here is my code for the call to the server to retrieve the data

```
public async Task<List<Portfolio>> GetAllPortfolios()
    {
        List<Portfolio> PortfolioList = new List<Portfolio>();
        Portfolio portfolio;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Connection))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            command.Connection = conn;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.CommandText = "USP_Get_All_Portfolios";
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

            //Fields to be populated
            string PortfolioName, Description, CreateID, UpdateID;

            while (await reader.ReadAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
                PortfolioName = reader["Portfolio_Name"].ToString();
                Description = reader["Long_Description"].ToString();
                CreateID = reader["Create_ID"].ToString();
                UpdateID = reader["Update_ID"].ToString();
                portfolio = new Portfolio(PortfolioName, Description, CreateID, UpdateID);
                PortfolioList.Add(portfolio);
            }
            reader.Close();
        }

        return PortfolioList;
    }
```

Code for my PortfolioService

```
public class PortfolioService : IPortfolioService
{
    private readonly IPortfolioRepository _portfolioRepository;

    public PortfolioService(IPortfolioRepository portfolioRepository)
    {
        _portfolioRepository = portfolioRepository;
    }
    public async Task<bool> CreatePortfolio(Portfolio portfolio)
    {
        return await _portfolioRepository.CreatePortfolio(portfolio).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    public async Task<List<Portfolio>> GetAllPortfolios()
    {
        return await _portfolioRepository.GetAllPortfolios().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

Code for my Portfolio class

```
public class Portfolio
{
    private string mPortfolioName;
    private string mDescription;
    private string mCreateID;
    private string mUpdateID;

    public string PortfolioName
    {
        get { return mPortfolioName; }
        set { mPortfolioName = value; }
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get { return Description; }
        set { mDescription = value; }
    }

    public string CreateID
    {
        get { return mCreateID; }
        set { mCreateID = value; }
    }

    public string UpdateID
    {
        get { return UpdateID; }
        set { mUpdateID = value; }
    }

    public Portfolio(string portfolioName, string description, string createID, string updateID)
    {
        mPortfolioName = portfolioName;
        mDescription = description;
        mCreateID = createID;
        mUpdateID = updateID;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged into the code to see where it fails? (As an aside, I'd suggest using `camelCase` for local variables, and declaring local variables with minimal scope, but neither of those affects the stack overflow.)

Comment: is there any log file ? did you debug this code ?

Comment: There's only partial evidence for this, but I think that _portfolioService.GetAllPortfolios().ConfigureAwait(false) is recursive somehow. Check to make sure that _portfolioService is actually pointing to the desired object.

Comment: `GetAllPortfolios` calls `GetAllPortfolios` and you're getting a `StackOverflowException`which is what happens when our recursion is infinite. I'm not saying that's 100% it, but it's the guiltiest looking dude in the lineup. Put a breakpoint in `GetAllPortfolios`. Does it get hit more than once? What is the concrete type of `_portfolioService`? Is it the same as the class that this method is in?

Comment: Yes I have debug and it fails on the return portfolios. It does make it to the end and right at the end where it returns is where it fails.

Comment: Are you getting all the way through `GetAllPortfolios`? What does the `Portfolio` class look like? If you're getting to `return portfolios` in the controller, I would suspect that one of the properties on the `Portfolio` class is infinitely recursive, and you're getting a stack overflow when the class is serializing.

Comment: Yes I am getting all the way through GetAllPortfolios. I added my portfolio class for more info.

Comment: Shouldn't an async controller method return a `Task<ActionResult>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return `mUpdateId` in the `get` for `Portfolio.UpdateId`, and `mDescription` from `Portfolio.Description`.

What you're doing now is calling the `get` method for `Portfolio.UpdateId` within the `get` method.

Which calls `get`.

Which calls `get`.

etc...

When you return from the controller ASP.NET is serializing that class for you. When it's serializing, it's trying to get the value of `UpdateId` and that is causing the infinite recursion, which is causing the stack overflow.

Incidentally, any reason not to drop the private fields in favor of [Auto-Implemented Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties).

```csharp
public class Portfolio
{
    public string PortfolioName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string CreateID { get; set; }
    public string UpdateID { get; set; }

    public Portfolio(string portfolioName, string description, string createID, string updateID)
    {
        PortfolioName = portfolioName;
        Description = description;
        CreateID = createID;
        UpdateID = updateID;
    }
}
```

It might save you from making a simple typo like that in the future :).

Comment: And to return `mDescription` in the `get` of `Portfolio.Description`

Comment: Or, even better, use auto-implemented properties.

Comment: Thank you it work. I missed such a simple mistake. I appreciate everyone who helped.

Comment: Woof! I missed `Description`. Thanks, @Nenad.